# How can I add a label in a new column in pandas based on two consecutive values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe, `df`, with a single column, `extension`.
The values in `extension` column are cyclically increasing and decreasing like below:

```
extension
0.000
0.050
0.100
0.150
0.130
0.080
0.020
0.050
0.075
```

I'm trying to label each increasing and decreasing cycle like below:

```
extension lablel
0.000      1
0.050      1
0.100      1
0.150      1
0.130      1
0.080      1
0.020      1
0.050      2
0.075      2
```

I'm a bit stuck, and would appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['lablel']=df.extension.diff()#Find the difference between consecutive ros in the column extension
df['lablel']=(df.lablel.ge(0)&df.lablel.shift(1).le(0)|df.lablel.ge(0)&df.lablel.shift(-1).le(0)).cumsum()+1#Find zero crossing from the consecutive differences, cummulatively sum and add 1 to the outcome



 extension  lablel
0      0.000       1
1      0.050       1
2      0.100       1
3      0.150       2
4      0.130       2
5      0.080       2
6      0.020       2
7      0.050       3
8      0.075       3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! you helped me a lot. but one more quick question. How about if I want to label a whole cycle when? I mean instead of labeling each increasing and decreasing in extension column, label a set of increasing and decreasing as a one cycle. for example extension starts from 0 goes up to 0.1, and comes back to 0.05. How can label all of this as one cycle?

Comment: Not sure I gor you. Edit your question and include sample output. Let me know once done and will help

Comment: Lets try `df['lablel']=df.extension.diff()` and then 
`df['lablel']=(df.lablel.ge(0)&df.lablel.shift(1).le(0)).cumsum()+1`

Comment: Does that help, happy to help further

Answer (score 1):

So lets reproduce your data:

```
a = [0.000,0.050,0.100,0.150,0.130,0.080,0.020,0.050,0.075]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["extension"])
```

***The short answer is this:***

```
df["label"] = pd.Series(np.where(df["extension"].diff() < 0, 0, 1)).diff().abs().cumsum() + 1
df.at[0,"label"] = 1
```

At least that's my answer. But it definitly looks a bit clunky. So let's **break it down** step by step for understanding:

```
df["extension"].diff()
```

`diff` creates the difference between each cell and the previous. Therefore it cannot calculate it for the first element.

**Output:**

```
0      NaN
1    0.050
2    0.050
3    0.050
4   -0.020
5   -0.050
6   -0.060
7    0.030
8    0.025
```

Now let's **binarize** the result to detect changes in **positive/negative** difference, using `where` from numpy:

```
np.where(df["extension"].diff() < 0, 0, 1)
```

**Output:**

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

This tells us if difference to previous is negative (--> 0) or positive (--> 1)

Then you want to know only when the positive/negative trend changes. Therefore we incorporate the `diff` function once more. Beforehand we have to convert the numpy array back to a `pd.Series`:

```
pd.Series(np.where(df["extension"].diff() < 0, 0, 1)).diff()
```

**Output:**

```
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4   -1.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    1.0
8    0.0
```

Ultimately you're not interested in which direction the trend has changed, only THAT it changed, therefore we erase this information with the `abs` function. And then sum the result up with the `cumsum` function so that it can increase on every change:

```
pd.Series(np.where(df["extension"].diff() < 0, 0, 1)).diff().abs().cumsum()
```

**Output:**

```
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
```

Finally two additions to base the label at 1 rather than 0 and to replace the first item that was NaN:
+1 behind the code and `df.at[0,"label"] = 1`

And there you go:

```
         extension  label
    0      0.000    1.0
    1      0.050    1.0
    2      0.100    1.0
    3      0.150    1.0
    4      0.130    2.0
    5      0.080    2.0
    6      0.020    2.0
    7      0.050    3.0
    8      0.075    3.0
```

**EDIT: answer to edited question in the comments**

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your thorough explaination. I just edit the question a bit, would you please take a quick look at it?

Comment: Mathematically your first request was simpler because this would technically be the inflection points of a mathematical graph. However, sticking with the current approach we could say, that technically you only need **half** the frequency of label increasing. This can be done with a simple `/ 2` and then erase the half numbers with a np.floor: `df["label"] = np.floor(pd.Series(np.where(df["extension"].diff() < 0, 0, 1)).diff().abs().cumsum() / 2) + 1` and then `df.at[0,"label"] = 1`

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I used @wwnde suggestion, and it's working. But thanks for your help!